# Perl Until Loop not matching with <STDIN>

Tags: perl, loops, stdin, xlsx

I'm using the Spreadsheet::XLSX plugin on this one and I'm trying to get IP Information out of a spreadsheet based on a user provided unique 'location code' (Designated as $xxcode).

My goal is to find the row number for the 'location code' given in the spreadsheet and then collect data, the problem I'm running into is that only when the 'location code' provided is the first result will the until loop actually break. Other wise it runs until the XLSX is over and errors out.

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use Spreadsheet::XLSX;
my $iplog = Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new ('C:\path\workbook.xlsx',);
my %iplogcol = ( "ip" => 2, "subnet" => 3, "gw" => 4, "locdes" => 1 ); 
my $codecol = 0; 
my $row = 1;
my $xxcode = <STDIN>;
my $worksheet = $iplog -> Worksheet('Sheet1'); 
my $xxcell = $worksheet->get_cell($row,$codecol);
my $xxvalue = $xxcell->value();



 until ($xxcode==$xxvalue) { 
 my $xxcell = $worksheet->get_cell($row,$codecol);
 my $xxvalue = $xxcell->value();
 printf ("Current Code: $xxvalue\n Looking for: $xxcode\n");
 $row=$row+1;
 };


for my $loop (keys %iplogcol) { 
    my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell($row,$iplogcol{$loop});
    my $value = $cell->value();
    printf ("$loop value is: %s\n", $value);
    }
```

---

Out put when I run the Script using second value:

```
C:\Users\Josh\scripts\perl\prechecklist>precheck2.pl

 Please enter the site number you would like to configure:2124
Current Code: 2125
 Looking for: 2124

Current Code: 2124
 Looking for: 2124

Current Code: 2123
 Looking for: 2124

Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at C:\Users\Josh\scripts\perl\pr
echecklist\precheck2.pl line 23, <STDIN> line 1.
```

The last error 'Can't call method "value"..etc' is because the spreadsheet is blank after row 3

---

Here it is when I run the script using the first value:

```
C:\Users\Josh\scripts\perl\prechecklist>precheck2.pl

 Please enter the site number you would like to configure:2125

locdes value is: 100 East ABC St.
ip value is: 1.1.1.1
gw value is: 1.1.1.2
subnet value is: 255.255.255.252
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Joshua

Comment: You have to `chomp` things you read from `STDIN` to remove the EOL character.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot That is the same first advice that I would give as well.  However, if he really is wanting a numerical comparison, it should work anyway.

Comment: @Miller Yep, I realized that after commenting...it's actually a scoping issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are re-declaring `$xxvalue` inside your `until` loop. The new value is not used in the comparison, so you will loop forever. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $foo = 42;
my $bar = 17;

until ($foo == $bar) {
    say "Before 'my': $bar";

    my $bar = 42;

    say "After 'my': $bar";
}
```

will repeatedly output

```
Before 'my': 17
After 'my': 42
Before 'my': 17
After 'my': 42
```

Comment: Since I'm re-pulling the value from the spreadsheet as I increment the row, wouldn't I have to re-declare it?

Comment: No. Instead of `my $xxvalue = $xxcell->value();` do `$xxvalue = $xxcell->value();`